# Multiple relations in a single table using JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

Using SpringBoot 2.7.6 I'm trying to do a multiple relationship stored in one table.
I have one entity that is related with many entities in my DB.

#### Great Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GREAT_ENTITY")
public class GreatEntity {
    
    @Id
    @Column("ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mapperBy = "greatEntities")
    private List<EntityA> entitiyAList;

    @ManyToMany(mapperBy = "greatEntities")
    private List<EntityB> entitiyBList;
}
```

#### EntityA

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_A")
public class EntityA {
    
    @Id
    @Column("ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "REL_GREAT_ENTITY",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GREAT_ENTITY_ID")
    )
    @Where(clause = "ENTITY_TYPE = 1")
    private List<GreatEntity> greatEntities;
}
```

#### EntityB

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_B")
public class EntityB {
    
    @Id
    @Column("ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "REL_GREAT_ENTITY",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GREAT_ENTITY_ID")
    )
    @Where(clause = "ENTITY_TYPE = 2")
    private List<GreatEntity> greatEntities;
}
```

#### REL_GREAT_ENTITY

The table used for this relationship looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE "REL_GREAT_ENTITY" 
   (    
    "GREAT_ENTITY_ID " NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ENTITY_ID " NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ENTITY_TYPE" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "GREAT_ENTITY_REL_GREAT_ENTITY_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("GREAT_ENTITY_ID ")
    REFERENCES "GREAT_ENTITY" ("ID") ENABLE
   )
```

This data was inserted by the previous owner of the DB but can be added by using an INSERT query

```
INSERT INTO REL_GREAT_ENTITY(GREAT_ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_TYPE)
VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO REL_GREAT_ENTITY(GREAT_ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_TYPE)
VALUES (1,1,2);
```

```
   GREAT_ENTITY_ID ENTITY_ID ENTITY_TYPE
   --------------- --------- -----------
   1               1         1
   1               1         2
```

The ENTITY_TYPE defines witch entity is the GreatEntity associated to. 1 for EntityA and 2 for EntityB as it was defined in the @Where clause in both entities.

I've tried to add the @Where clause like in the example provided but when I retrieve the entities I got the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "GREATENTITY1_"."ENTITY_TYPE": identificador no válido
```

I also tried a workaround in order to fetch the data using:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "GREAT_ENTITY_ID in (SELECT rel.GREAT_ENTITY_ID FROM REL_GREAT_ENTITY rel WHERE rel.ENTITY_TYPE=1)")
    @JoinTable(
        name = "REL_GREAT_ENTITY ",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GREAT_ENTITY_ID")
    )
```

In this case I was able to retrieve the data by fetching the EntityA and then the EntityA.greatEntities belong only to the ENTITY_TYPE = 1

But I was not able to insert any record in the DB by persisting EntityA due to the DB didn't know the ENTITY_TYPE (NOT NULL value)

Comment: Please, add info how do you define ENTITY_TYPE column: entity class(es) where it is defined and other configurations, f.e. ENTITY_TYPE default value. And also add the code where you insert record into the DB: do you set ENTITY_TYPE to some value before saving?

Comment: Since EntityA and EntityB are independent from each other I would also use independent join tables.

Comment: In the real project I can't do that due to client desires. The real project has more than 50 entities referenced not just two of them like in the example.

Comment: As understand the JoinTable documentation you simply have to specify an SQL predicate (e.g. clause = "ENTITY_TYPE = 1") but not a complete query. Did you try this?

Comment: The issues isn't with reads - your @where clause tells Hibernate (this is NOT JPA) which REL_GREAT_ENTITY rows to use in which relationship. But Where is a filter applied to reads, not writes, so you have nothing in there specifying how to write this out. If you want a pure JPA approach, map REL_GREAT_ENTITY as an entity with inheritance, so you can use the ENTITY_TYPE as the inheritance discriminator for A and B subtypes. EntityA would have a OneToMany/ManyToOne with GreaterEntityRelA which has a ManyToOne/OneToMany with GreatEntity.

Comment: I see but the issue here is that GREAT_ENTITY is no the parent and should not be the parent of EntityA nor EntityB

Answer (score 0):

After some study of the situation the better way to solve this was creating in the database one table for each realation as said by [Karsten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22351796/karsten) in the comments.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).